# Cannot read 'component' of undefined: Using material-ui with browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I'm using browserify to manage my dependencies, as suggested on the material-ui setup doc. When I try to run my code, the console gives me this message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined`, which is traced back to `bundle.js:6769`

In my `bundle.js` file, line 6769 is the return statement of this function:

```
    getThemeButton: function getThemeButton() {
        return this.context.muiTheme.component.button;
    },
```

What am I missing here? I have require statements for both material-ui and the material-ui components that I am using.

The top of my index.js file looks like this:

```
    var React = require('react');
    var injectTapEventPlugin = require('react-tap-event-plugin');
    var mui = require('material-ui');
    var RaisedButton = mui.RaisedButton;

    injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Comment: There's not enough code there to see the problem. Have you defined the 'contextTypes' for your component?

Comment: I was missing exactly that. Now it works :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer hidden in the [docs](http://material-ui.com/#/customization/themes)!

Apparently this is a required part of material-ui (I don't know why they didn't include it as part of the set-up), but I needed to include this snippet in my rendered classes:

```
childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
},

getChildContext: function() {
    return {
      muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
    };
},
```