# react-bootstrap Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a modal window with react-bootstrap for my django app, I implemented the jsx file like this

```
const WindowModal = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
  return {showModal: false};
},

close(){
  this.setState({showModal: false});
},

open(){
  this.setState({showModal: true});
},


render () {
  return (

    <div>
         <p>Click!</p>

         <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" onClick={this.open}>Launch</Button>

         <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
           <Modal.Header closeButton>
             <Modal.Title>Sign Up</Modal.Title>
           </Modal.Header>
           <Modal.Body>
             <h1>Sign Up in Studio</h1>
           </Modal.Body>
           <Modal.Footer>
             <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
           </Modal.Footer>
         </Modal>
       </div>

  );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(< WindowModal/>,
document.getElementById('contenu')
);
```

but when I run my app I get errors in the browser console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to import or export a component correctly.

Comment: what do i need to import ?

Comment: importi el component sa7bi el béhii

Comment: The error is telling you that it can't find a component called "Component". It could also mean that you need childContextTypes or Context types needs to be defined. I am assuming that these components are using a flux architecture so you need to import modal and button.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717886/cannot-read-component-of-undefined-using-material-ui-with-browserify